# Intermittently uncommunicative subnets

Tags: linux, routing, subnet

Last week proved me a veritable Cassandra: I've always said that it's a bad idea to have only one firewall/router, without a backup or failover. And thus our Cisco PIX went haywire, refusing to route properly. And of course, the only one available here on short notice is me, and while I'm quite grounded in Linux, I'm really a developer not a sysadmin (the fact that this hit me on sysadmin appreciation day is a bit ironic).

Anyway, this weekend I tried to hack up a temporary solution: I used an old server with enough NICs (two built-in, four on a card) to serve as a gateway and firewall. Due to some problems with the raid controller, I got only two router distros running, and between Untangle and Ebox I decided for the latter.

Now everything is quite okay. I've got all the different subnets we've got here (all with separate switches) talking to each other and even to the internet (Cisco 2800 router, T1 lines). But from time to time (20-60 minute intervals), I get a total routing failure. Our main, office subnet can't talk to our server subnet and can't connect to the internet. This is not the end of a gradual slowdown, either everything's working perfectly or I get a total lack of communication for about two minutes each time.

Now I'm a bit at wits end what to check. At least with the default EBox setup, nothing in /var/log shows anything weird and it doesn't exactly have lots of built-in monitoring tools. So I'm hoping someone here could give me some pointers about what to look out for. I did change the ethernet cable from the office switch to the firewall, with no results. I might change switches, although within the switch it seems to work ok enough.

**Edit**: I'm not sure whether this is the sole cause of the problem, but after I noticed a few DHCP entries just before the last drop of connectivity, I tried to reproduce that. And alas, whenever I renew a DHCP connection, I can't access other subnets anymore. Running ISC DHCPD 3.0.6.

Answer (score 1):

Are there any firmware updates available for your NICs? If it is a very old server, perhaps intermittent connection issues have been resolved in an update? At the very least it wouldn't hurt to browse through any firmware release notes so see if an issue like this is mentioned at all.

Comment: I haven't found any downloadable firmware, an the one included in the linux kernel is pretty current. Worked fine as a fileserver before. Changing it to the other network card (different chipset) seems to give me the same errors.

Comment: @mhd - I think you may be confusing firmware with a driver. Regardless, if it happens on your other NICs as well, it's likely not a firmware issue.

Comment: A lot of drivers need firmware loaded into the hardware, including the broadcom NIC in the server. That's what /lib/firmware is for. (And is a constant source of complaints by the free software people)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely do check dmesg (the output of the command, not just the one in /var/log/)  I would check out netstat -s and compare it to the various ip limits from "sysctl -a".  Especially if you're doing NAT on it, you could be hitting some sort of connection limit.

You might try rigging a script to get a packet dump on one of the interfaces during the outage.  Something like "while [1]; do ping -c 1  || tcpdump -s 0 -i eth0 -c 100; sleep 10; done"

Answer (score 1):

20-60 seconds sounds like [spanning-tree reconvergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree_protocol). Check your switch logs (I assume these are managed switches) and figure out what is being unplugged/replugged that is causing the convergence. If its a device with a single cable going to the switch, set that switchport to portfast. Or you could always dig to the root cause and find out what is causing the port to go on and off. :D Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Also check `dmesg` to see if there's anything network-related in there. Some drivers will occasionally go unresponsive due to a variety of driver/card-related problems.